# Slim framework PDO PGSQL, not binding parameters

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, slim

I'm having a little bit of an issue with PDO binding Parameters.

My setup is as follows.

- Ubuntu Desktop 16.04
- Netbeans 8.1 (php and html only version)
- php cli 7.0.4 (Running internal web server)
- Postgres SQL 9.5
- Slim Framework 3

I have opted to use PDO to access my database. This is my learning the system for a future project.

I can grab all records from a table, I can get the argument issued in the uri to echo on screen.

But using the GET method to locate a specific entry throws the following error at me.

```
{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[08P01]: <>: 7 ERROR: bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000001" requires 1}}
```

The following is my code.

db.php

```
<?php
function getDB() {
    $dbtype="pgsql";
    $dbhost="localhost";
    $dbuser="postgres";
    $dbpass="SomeSecurePassword";
    $dbname="bms";
    $dbConnection = new PDO("$dbtype:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbConnection;
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'db.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/','getRoot');
$app->get('/contacts', 'getContacts');
$app->get('/contacts/{contact_id}', 'getContact');

$app->run();

function getRoot() {
echo 'This is the Root URI';
}

function getContacts() {
$sql = "SELECT last_name,first_name FROM contacts ORDER BY last_name DESC";
try {
    $db = getDB();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $contacts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo '{"Contacts": ' . json_encode($contacts) . '}';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
}

function getContact(Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
$contact_id = (int)$args['contact_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact_id = :contact_id";
try {
    $db = getDB();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':contact_id', $contact_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->debugDumpParams();
    $db = null;
    echo '{"Contact": ' . json_encode($contact) . '}';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
}
```

Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use prepared statements.

```
$stmt = $db->query($sql); //Executes a query and returns a statement
```

What you want is...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':contact_id', $contact_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```